# How to get Isotope Wordpress plugin mintthemes work?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, jquery-isotope

I have installed the WordPress plugin Isotope from Mintthemes. But I don't get it to work. I have set the following snippet of code in my page.php and also filled in the optional settings for usage of custom post types.

```
<?php moveplugins_isotopes(); ?>
```

Added categories to my custom post type portfolio items but it doesn't work.

**My code:**

```
<?php moveplugins_isotopes(); ?>

<ul class="entrybox">
<?php 
    $args = array('post_type' => 'portfolio');
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<?php if ($loop->have_posts()) : while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <li class="grid_4 portfolio-post">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="<?php print IMAGES; ?>/portfolio/thumbnails/thumbnail.png" alt="Thumbnail">
    </div><!-- End .thumbnail -->
    </a>

    <div class="description">
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div><!-- End div.description -->
    </li><!-- End li.grid_4 projectbox -->

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul><!-- End ul.entrybox -->
```

Comment: did you put it in above the loop?

Comment: @DavidChase Yes I put the function above the loop. I will use this for my custom post type - Portfolio.

Comment: @DavidChase This is how the markup looks like: http://snippi.com/s/y0qqvc9

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your li isn't using the post_class function in WordPress. It uses that post_class to identify which items are in the loop.

It should be something like

```
<li class="<?php post_class( array('grid_4', 'portfolio-post') ) ?>">
```

You can find out more about it here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class